# White space at bottom of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I open my webpage (code and link below) there is a gap at the bottom of the page making the page slightly more than 100% height which causes the scroll bar to appear needlessly.

I know this has been asked before and I have looked through several answers to this question and I can't get any of them to work (don't rule out me doing it wrong though). I can't figure out whether the gap is being caused by Javascript, CSS or the HTML. I have been fiddling with the CSS for a while and nothing seems to be making a difference so If you spot something I've missed please tell me.

Interestingly the scroll bar disappears while the JavaScript to open and close the curtains is running but instantly reappears after it finishes.

Here is the HTML and Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>
      The Randoms
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js">
</script>
    <script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

                        $curtainopen = false;

                        $(".rope").click(function(){
                                $(this).blur();
                                if ($curtainopen == false){ 
                                        $(this).stop().animate({top: '0px' }, {queue:false, duration:350, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
                                        $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({width:'60px'}, 2000 );
                                        $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({width:'60px'},2000 );
                                        $curtainopen = true;
                                }else{
                                        $(this).stop().animate({top: '-40px' }, {queue:false, duration:350, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
                                        $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({width:'50%'}, 2000 );
                                        $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({width:'51%'}, 2000 );
                                        $curtainopen = false;
                                }
                                return false;
                        });

                });     
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.fade').fadeIn(3000, function() {
    // Animation complete
    });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.rope').fadeIn(3000, function() {
    // Animation complete
    });
    }, 3000);
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function runMyFunction() {
    $(".fade").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
    return true;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="leftcurtain">
      <img src="images/frontcurtain.jpg" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="rightcurtain">
      <img src="images/frontcurtain.jpg" alt="Image">
    </div><a class="rope" href="#" onclick="return runMyFunction();"><img src="images/rope.png"
    alt="Image"></a>
    <div class="fade" id="fade">
      <h1>
        Ever wanted to know what's behind the curtain?
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>
        Place Holder
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
html
{
height=100%;
}

*
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
}

body 
{
text-align: center;
background-color: #C20D19;
max-height:100%;
}

h1
{
margin-top: 0;
}

p,li
{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif; 
margin: 12px;
color:#ffffff
}

div
{
margin: 0;
max-height: 100%;
}

div#content
{
padding: 0;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 80%;
width: 1000px;
height: 100%;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif; 
background-color: #000000;
}

img
{
border: none;
}

.leftcurtain
{
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
}

 .rightcurtain
 {
width: 51%;
height: 100%;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
}

.rightcurtain img, .leftcurtain img
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.rope
{
position: absolute;
top: -40px;
left: 80%;
z-index: 4;
display:none;
}


.fade
{
z-index: 5;
position: absolute;
display: none;
}

#fade
{
top: 80px;
left: 50%;
width: 250px;
height: 0 auto;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif; 
}
```

If you think the referenced JavaScript to control the curtains movement is import you can find it at http://www.osholt.co.uk/concepts/jquery.easing.1.3.js.

To see the issue in action go to http://www.osholt.co.uk/concepts

This is my first project involving JavaScript so if you see anything wrong with what I've done please alert me to that as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help you debug if you clean up your CSS some. You set `margin:0` like four times for a number of elements.

Comment: You also have CSS syntax errors which was pointed out by Jrod below.

Answer (score 4):

Add `overflow: hidden` on `body`.

```
body 
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #C20D19;
    max-height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Edit:** Another solution would be to add `display: block;` to the curtain images.  This seems to be the real culprit.  It fixes IE 7 as well:

```
.rightcurtain img, .leftcurtain img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I am an idiot for not spotting that. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @user798095:  This just masks your problem by simply hiding anything overflowing the screen thereby avoiding scroll-bars.  This will not be good when you make the window smaller and you actually _need_ scroll-bars to appear.

Comment: @Sparky - I humbly disagree.  Setting `max-height: 100%` on `body` implies the developer is trying to prevent scrollbars from ever appearing.  The only way to force that behavior is by hiding the overflow.  However, you are correct - while acheiving the desired effect, it does not truly address the real issue.  Namely, what in the world is pushing the page outside of its boundaries?  It turns out it was the `<img>` tags.  Being inline elements, they ignored the margin instructions.  Changing their display to block fixes it.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I had a different but related problem that the 2nd part fixed (setting display:block on the image tag). Thanks!

Comment: This is a fantastic bit of advice - a slight variation on this fixed white gaps that were appearing when I was showing a mask overlay. I'm using Sencha Touch 1 on a Samsung Galaxy S3. And amazingly also fixed similar mask sizing issues that were occurring after device rotation - .x-mask { height: 105% !important; overflow: hidden; } - Thanks a million for the post.

Comment: And it has even fixed an issue with the latest desktop Chrome browser (26.0.1410.64 m) with scrollbars starting to reappear if you switched tabs. body { overflow: hidden; } - big thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
html
{
height=100%;
}
```

Should Probably be

```
html
{
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the height of your "curtain" containers that is causing the scrollbars to pop up. It seems that you are forgetting that the "curtains" would push the "border" of the container object (namely the div outside it and the body outside that) when their size exceeds the height of the screen. The problem with max-height is that its interpretation is pretty sketchy at best.

I'd suggest you switch to 99% instead of 100% for the curtain values. That makes your scrollbar go away.

Of course, you could use the overflow attribute as well; however, if something exceeds the width of your display it will not be visible (since "overflow" affects both X and Y). There is also overflow-y, which would affect only the y axis; however, not all browsers fully support that.